# py2neo establish new edges between existing nodes

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo, edges

Let's say I wanted to merge new edges into my graph between 2 adjacent nodes (so that after the operation the edges in question are doubled so to speak).

I have the following record returned by `graph.cypher.execute(<some query>)`:

```
   | p                         
---+----------------------------
 1 | (:A)-[:r]->(:B)-[:r]->(:C)
```

Now I would like to double the edges (A,B) and (B,C). For that i wrote this code:

```
for record in graph.cypher.execute(<some query>):
    for rel in record[0]:
            self.graph.cypher.execute("MERGE "+str(self.graph.node(rel.start_node.ref))+"-[:new]->"+str(self.graph.node(rel.end_node.ref)))
```

However, I do not get new edges between the existing nodes but two new relationships with a total of 4 new nodes, because apparently NEO4J does not interpret `str(self.graph.node(rel.start_node.ref))` and `str(self.graph.node(rel.end_node.ref))` as referring to the existing nodes in the graph. How can I remedy this?

Answer (score 1):

`self.graph.create(rel(r.start_node, "new", r.end_node))` does it.

needs `from py2neo import rel`